# Openlayers 2.x : Does not refresh WFS vector layer after adding another vector layer

Tags: vector, openlayers, geoserver

This is just a snippet of my code:

```
function removeFilter(a){
    if (a === "100-Year Rainfall"){
        bldg100yearCBR.filter = null;
        bldg100yearCBR.refresh({
            force: true
        });     
    }
...
```

Above is my function to remove filter for WFS vector layer. It works if I won't add another layer. I am wondering why? Here's how I add my layer:

```
 bldg100yearCBR = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("100-Year Rainfall Affected Buildings", {
            strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
            eventListeners: {           
                'loadend': function (evt) {
                    map.zoomToExtent(bldg100yearCBR.getDataExtent());
                    //map.getExtent().containsBounds(bldg100yearCBR, true);
                    $("#load_table").removeAttr("disabled", "disabled");
                    $("#load_table").val("Go"); 
                    $("#locateMe").hide();  
                    },
                'loadstart': function (evt) {               
                    $("#load_table").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                    $("#load_table").val("Loading...");
                    $("#locateMe").show();                      
                    }
            },
            projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
            protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
                version: "1.1.0",
                url: a,
                featureType: "bldg_100yr",
                featureNS: b,
                geometryName: "geom"
            }),
            renderers: renderer,
            styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap(style),
            displayInLayerSwitcher: !0      
        });
        var selFloodEvent = $('#affectedLayer').val(); 
        var layerName  = map.getLayersByName(selFloodEvent);
        var len =  layerName.length;
        if (len < 1){
            map.addLayer(bldg100yearCBR);
            activateControls(c);
        }else{
        removeFilter("100-Year Rainfall");
        layerName[0].setVisibility(true);
        console.log("reset me");
        }           
        myflag1 = true;
        toggleStatic1("100-Year Rainfall Affected Buildings");
```

After adding/loading another vector layer, filter won't work. The scenario is if the layer is already loaded, I want to display it without adding it again but if it is filtered before, I wanted to reset it. That's the problem, the `removeFilter` function won't work after loading another vector layer.

So, basically filter only works the first time I loaded the layer. I also noticed in console log in my browser, it does not query to the GeoServer like this:

`XHR finished loading: POST "http://127.0.0.1:8080/geoserver/wfs".`

after loading another layer.